# removeFromSuperview() doesn't work for swift when called within touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift

I add a UITextView named textView within the method didMove(to view:), and want to remove within the method touchedBegan. But removeFromSuperview() doesn't work. The textView's superview is nil but the self.view's subviews still contain the textView.

If I called textView.removeFromSuperview within didMove(to view:), it would be removed from the self.view.

Even when I set textView.isHidden = true, the textView is still on the screen.

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class InputScene: GameScene,UITextViewDelegate {

    var textView: UITextView!{
    willSet {
        //willSet the subview: Optional([])
        //willSet the subview: Optional([<UITextView: 0x7f94b80c1800; frame = (20 198.667; 374 200); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600001a05cb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001418a00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {374, 192}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>])
        print("willSet the subview: \(self.view?.subviews)")
        return
    }
}
    var transLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Go to Game Scene.")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Set the textView
        backgroundColor = .white
        textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: self.size.width-40, height: 200))
        textView.center = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/3)
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        // Add subview and show that it has been added
        self.view?.addSubview(textView)

        // Print self.view's for the first time.
        //The subviews: [<UITextView: 0x7fbe3984f600; frame = (20 198.667; 374 200); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600001c5da40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000124af40>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {374, 192}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>]
        //The subviews: [<UITextView: 0x7fbe3984f600; frame = (20 198.667; 374 200); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600001c5da40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000124af40>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {374, 192}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>, <UITextView: 0x7fbe3a84cc00; frame = (20 198.667; 374 200); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600001c58d20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001244f00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {374, 192}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>]
        print("The subviews: \(view.subviews)")

        // Add transfer label
        transLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        transLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
        addChild(transLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return
        }
        if transLabel.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
                self.textView.removeFromSuperview()
                self.textView.isHidden = true

            // Print the textView's superview
            // The textView's superview: nil
            print("The textView's superview: \(String(describing: textView.superview))")

            // Print the self.view's subview for the second time.
            // The self.view's subview still contains the textView
            // The subviews: Optional([<UITextView: 0x7fc60b8a9000; frame = (20 198.667; 374 200); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000332a280>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003d30ce0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {374, 192}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>])
            print("The subviews: \(String(describing: self.view?.subviews))")
            textView.removeFromSuperview()
            view?.presentScene(SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"))
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that the printed "subviews" is doubled is because that didMoveToView is fired twice when the scene is presented. It is because Xcode sets up a dummy version of the scene first, then the real scene. It will not cause any errors.

I tried to set the textView to be weak but it doesn't appear at all.

Even I didn't do view?.presentScene(SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")), the textView still can't be removed. I try to set the InputScene a subclass of SKScene but not a subclass of GameScene, but it can't help.

I try to print textView's description in the touchesBegan method, and it turns out self.views's subview is not the expected "textView".

Comment: Are you adding more than you think? Maybe you are deleting textView, however, you created 3 textViews on accident and only are deleting the last 1, making it seem like there is only 1 and it is not getting deleted.

Comment: I let it print self.view's subviews in the console twice, and the only one of the subview is that textView.

Comment: Yea, show us how you did that. Prove to us, in the code's entirety, that you have done it correctly. That is where we will find your problem.

Comment: I modified the code to indicated the two printed statement in the comment.

Comment: The first is within didMoveTo and the second is in touchesBegan

Comment: It prints 2 of the same thing; that looks like that you created 2 of the same variable. You have `//The subviews: [<UITextView: 0x7fbe3984f600; frame = (20 198.667; 374 200); text = ''; ... <UITextView: 0x7fbe3a84cc00; frame = (20 198.667; 374 200); text = ''; ` which makes me think you have created 2 textViews. Show me  where you create textViews.

Comment: But the thing is that even I called textView.removeFromSuperview in the touchesBegan twice, it cannot remove this textView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are not explaining is how there came to be two text views. There clearly are two text views, because we can see that in these logs:

```
// The subviews: [<UITextView: 0x7fbe3984f600 ....
// The subviews: Optional([<UITextView: 0x7fc60b8a9000....
```

Those are two different address values, so those are two different text views. The implication is that at some time (perhaps not shown in your question?) you are coming along and adding another text view to `self.view`.

If that is so, and if each time you add a text view you set the value of `textView`, you lose your reference to the first text view. Let's assume that you are right and that you are accidentally doing this *twice:*

```
textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: self.size.width-40, height: 200))
self.view?.addSubview(textView)
```

Now, the second time you do that, you effectively eject the first text view from its place as the referent of `textView` and replace it with the second. So now, how can you ever tell the first text view to `removeFromSuperview()`? Remember, `textView` no longer refers to it. Telling `textView` to `removeFromSuperview()` multiple times isn't going to help, because the first text view is not referred to by `textView` any longer.

Comment: A good way to confirm or deny this hypothesis would be simply to put a setter observer on the `textView` property and add a breakpoint to it. Now your code will stop each time `textView` is set and you can see how it is getting set — twice, if that's what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are right. There are two separate text views. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are right and the textView is added twice, a simple solution would be checking whether the textView is nil or not, based on that you can decide if it's need to be added

declare the textView as nil at first-

```
var textView: UITextView?
```

and then you can call

```
if textView != nil{
    textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 0, width: self.size.width-40, height: 200))
    textView.center = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/3)
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    // Add subview and show that it has been added
    self.view?.addSubview(textView)
}
```

**Edit**

I've just played with your code a little and I think I managed to find the cause of that problem.
Sadly I'm not a SpriteKit expert so we'll have to wait for one to get a solution, for now I'm defining the problem.

in short- `view?.presentScene(SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"))` renders GameScene all over again

Here's what I've done-

I've set up a counter inside the class to keep track on didMove function, but it turns out the counter is being reset after every tap- every presentScene call.

then I've added a required init to keep track on that, and it turns out presentScene/(tap) caused the required init to run again, so the whole class is being reloaded when presentScene is called.

It's important to tell that when I defined counter outside the class' scope he kept track as normal- that strengthens the above.

In your case it just added the textview immediately after it was removed- and checking if it was nil didn't help because it was nil- the class reloaded all over again

On launch-
[image: On launch]
After one tap-[image]

Comment: I have tried but nothing changed. Thank you for your help any way.

Comment: I am sorry but even if I don't go to GameScene, the textView still cannot be removed.

Comment: You can consider your InputScene as my GameScene for that case- Write down the required init and print when it’s called- just like I did. You should get the same results as I did